# Loop over an array and create form input tags after labels

Tags: javascript, loops, form-fields

Im trying to loop over an array to create some form tags, depending on how many values there are in the array. So far i have got my label and input tags that are being created. The problem i am having is displaying the input tags correctly after the labels. Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm trying to achieve:

```
<label class="material-label" for="leather_materials">
<input id="leather_materials" class="shoe-materials" type="radio" name="materials" value="leather">
<label class="material-label" for="suade_materials">
<input id="suade_materials" class="shoe-materials" type="radio" name="materials" value="suade">
<label class="material-label" for="nubuck_materials">
<input id="nubuck_materials" class="shoe-materials" type="radio" name="materials" value="nubuck">
```

my code so far:

```
materialArray = ['leather','suade','nubuck'];

//loop over material array 
for( i = 0; i < materialArray.length;  i++) {

    //create label elements
    var matLabel = document.createElement('label');
    matLabel.setAttribute('for', materialArray[i] + '_materials');
    matLabel.setAttribute('class', 'material-label');
    console.log(matLabel);

    //add text to label elements
    var matLabelTextNode = document.createTextNode(materialArray[i]);
    matLabel.appendChild(matLabelTextNode);

    //create input elements
    var matInput = document.createElement('input');
    matInput.className = 'shoe-materials';
    matInput.setAttribute('class', 'shoe-materials');
    matInput.setAttribute('id', materialArray[i] +'_materials');
    matInput.setAttribute('name', 'materials');
    matInput.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    matInput.setAttribute('value', materialArray[i]);
    console.log(matInput);   

    //append to parent div
    addMaterials.appendChild(matLabel);    
    $('.material-label').after(matInput);        
}
```

I tried using jQuery after() but it went a bit messed up and got the following

```
<label class="material-label" for="leather_materials">leather</label>
<input id="nubuck_materials" class="shoe-materials" type="radio" name="materials" value="nubuck">
<input id="suade_materials" class="shoe-materials" type="radio" name="materials" value="suade">
<input id="leather_materials" class="shoe-materials" type="radio" name="materials" value="leather">
<label class="material-label" for="suade_materials">suade</label>
<input id="nubuck_materials" class="shoe-materials" type="radio" name="materials" value="nubuck">
<input id="suade_materials" class="shoe-materials" type="radio" name="materials" value="suade">
<label class="material-label" for="nubuck_materials">nubuck</label>
<input id="nubuck_materials" class="shoe-materials" type="radio" name="materials" value="nubuck">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change '.material-label' to matLabel

```
$(matLabel).after(matInput);
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/82o6hfna/

Comment: I cant believe it was that easy! I have been pulling my hair out. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Mistake you're doing is appending those elements after the `.material-label` element. So you keep adding them after the labels which has already that class.

**From :**

```
$('.material-label').after(matInput);
```

**To:**

```
$(matLabel).after(matInput);
```

**Updated code:**

```js
var addMaterials = document.getElementById("addMaterials");
materialArray = ['leather','suade','nubuck'];

//loop over material array 
for( i = 0; i < materialArray.length;  i++) {

    //create label elements
    var matLabel = document.createElement('label');
    matLabel.setAttribute('for', materialArray[i] + '_materials');
    matLabel.setAttribute('class', 'material-label');
    console.log(matLabel);

    //add text to label elements
    var matLabelTextNode = document.createTextNode(materialArray[i]);
    matLabel.appendChild(matLabelTextNode);

    //create input elements
    var matInput = document.createElement('input');
    matInput.className = 'shoe-materials';
    matInput.setAttribute('class', 'shoe-materials');
    matInput.setAttribute('id', materialArray[i] +'_materials');
    matInput.setAttribute('name', 'materials');
    matInput.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    matInput.setAttribute('value', materialArray[i]);
    console.log(matInput);   

    //append to parent div
    addMaterials.appendChild(matLabel);    
    $(matLabel).after(matInput);        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="addMaterials"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery statement `$('.material-label')` selects every element with that class, so when you use `$('.material-label').after(matInput)`, you are adding the contents of matInput after each of the three labels.

To get the current label, just use `i` as the index for the array returned by `$('.material-label')`.

Changing

```
//append to parent div
addMaterials.appendChild(matLabel);
$('.material-label').after(matInput);
```

To

```
//append to parent div
currentLabel = $('.material-label')[i];
$(currentLabel).after(matInput);
```

Will get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

I never liked the object manipulation approach to building html.  I like to build the string of html then insert it into the dom.  Just my opinion.

## JS

```
//to uppercase of first letter only
String.prototype.toUpperCaseFirstLetter = function() {
    var s = this;
    return s.length > 0 ? s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1) : s;
}

var materialArray = ['leather','suade','nubuck'];

function buildMaterialRadios () {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < materialArray.length; i++) {
      var item = materialArray[i];
      str += '<label class="material-label" for="'+item+'_materials">'+item.toUpperCaseFirstLetter()+'</label><input id="'+item+'_materials" class="shoe-materials" type="radio" name="materials" value="'+item+'">';
    };

    document.getElementById('material_selections').innerHTML = str;
}


buildMaterialRadios();
```

## HTML

```
<form name="shoebuilderform">

<div id="material_selections"></div>

</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qcmdnd4d/